# '-replace' various parts of a variable's output, matching whole word and word only

Tags: regex, powershell, scripting

So in writing this PowerShell script, part of the output to the console includes "Warning Report To First.Last removed". That's what's intended, but what I really get is:

```
 WARNING: @{name=Report to firstname.lastname} removed
```

I'm trying to exclude @{name=} meaning each of those characters and in that order. So I can remove the @, the =, and the two curly braces with

```
-replace '[@{=}]',''
```

However I've been unable to figure out how to remove the word 'name'. If I try something like:

```
-replace '[@{name=}]',''
```

It also remove other instances of those letters.. Is there a way to match an entire word but exclude singular occurrences of the letters?

Comment: It does not sound clear. To remove a word `name` or `@`, or `=`, or `{` or `}` you need to use `-replace 'name|[@{=}]'` or `-replace '\bname\b|[@{=}]'`. To remove `{@name=` and `}` you may use `-replace '@{name=([^{}]*)}', '$1'`

Comment: How did you obtain the input string in the first place? Sounds like you're missing a `.Name` reference earlier in your script

Comment: This looks like the output of a `| Select-Object -Property Name` statement, converted to string. If this is the case use the `-ExpandProperty` switch to only output the value of the property, without the surrounding object: `| Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you really mean, but I wanna point out that you need to remove the square brackets [] . With them, the regex will match on any occurrence of the single characters inside the brackets. If you're looking for the entire sequence and not single characters, just remove those brackets, using just   @{name=}   which will ignore single characters but match the whole expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what your issue is- you've got a few questions here that should probably be asked separately.

For the regex at least, don't put the word in square brackets if searching a sequence of letters. [name] means any of the the letters n, a, m, e.

Example-

```
$InputString = 'WARNING: @{name=Report to firstname.lastname} removed' 
$InputString -replace '@{name=|}',''
```

Returns

```
WARNING: Report to firstname.lastname removed
```

Comment: Mind that `@{name=|}` will replace `}` anywhere, not only in a `@{name=...}` substring.

Comment: Actually two of you answered it beautifully.  OwlSleeping and zett42.. both of ya'lls suggestions worked great in my case!  Thank you!!!